# Jquery and Asynchronous Methods in popup.html

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm playing around with building chrome extensions. I'm currently testing out the popup.html functionality when you click on the icon in the tool bar.

However I'm having a difficult time trying to wrap my head around using jquery in conjunction with the asynchronous methods of chrome.* apis. Maybe someone can elaborate further for me?

Scenario

popup.html contains buttons that interact with the current tab, The button's href is generated based on the current tab's url + additional text from an array. Using jQuery, I have a $("button").click(); inside of a document is ready. However these two do not seem to play nicely. Everything except for the jQuery stuff works.

example.

```
var the_current_url = '';
var url_addition = {
    "button 1" : "/home",
    "button 2" : "/about",
    "button 3" : "/content"
}

function getCurrentURL(currentURL) {

if(currentURL) {

    var scheme = currentURL.match(/^https?:\/\//i);
    var newURL = '';

    currentURL = currentURL.substring( scheme[0].length, currentURL.length );
    currentURL = currentURL.substring( 0, currentURL.indexOf("/") );

    the_current_url = newURL.concat(scheme[0], currentURL);

}

return true;
}

function buildButtons() {

var new_code = "<ul>\n";

// Generate the <li>
for (var key in url_addition) {

    new_code = new_code.concat("<li><a href=\"",
        the_current_url.concat(url_addition[key]),
        "\" title=\"",
            url_addition[key],
            "\">",
            key,
            "</a></li>\n");
}

new_code = new_code.concat("</ul>");


return new_code;
}

// Get the Current URL and build the new url
chrome.tabs.query({

    'active': true

    }, function(tab) {

    var currentURL = tab[0].url;

    // Pass the Current URL to bb_current_url via Function
    getCurrentURL(currentURL);

    // add the popup buttons
    document.getElementById("button-container").innerHTML = buildButtons();

});


$(document).ready(function() {

// Clicked on buttons
$("a").parents("#button-container").click(function() {
    console.log("test" );
});

});
```

I'm able to get the current tab's url and build the buttons with the proper links, however when it comes to the jquery click action don't work. It seems like the jquery stuff happens before the button-container's buttons are created. So that the $("a")'s click doesn't return any output to the console.log. Anyone know how I'm suppose to correctly use chrome's api with jquery in this instance?

Comment: Why are you using the $("a").parents("#button-container") - construct? "#button-container" is an id - selektor giving you exactly one element. So you could just shorten this expression to ("#button-container").click(function() {
    console.log("test" );
});

Comment: There are multiple a hrefs inside my div id of "#button-container", so I want to distinguish a hrefs that have a parent of "#button-container". Note it's .parents and not .parent, so the div layer could be several levels up.

Comment: The other way round: ("#button-container").children('a').click(function() { console.log('test');});

Comment: Your selector first searches every existing A-href element in the whole document, down - traversing from <html> and then upwards again to find the tree from the found a-hrefs to button-container.

Comment: This might even give you a null - value for a-hrefs outside of '#button-container', which then a click - function should be attached to.

Comment: If you would like to find only immediate childs of '#button-container', the selector would be '#button-container > a'

Comment: But as fare as I can see ,none of your a-hrefs is attached to button-conainer directly but rather wrapped into a <li> - element.

Comment: so by far the easiest an most clear approach would be giving the a-hrefs you want to attach the clic-function to a class - attribute and then use the '.class' -selector. Combined : $('#button-container .classname).click ...

Comment: for the a-href's that are inside '#button-container' in your current selector '#button-container' itself would be returned, leaving you with the task of resolving the actual click - target (a-href) you would have to know, propably. Though this can be a peformance - increasement I personally avoid things like that unless they are necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the many replies everyone. I know that my jquery element works when I don't generate the button list from the callback function of chrome.tabs.query. So it's not an issue with it's structure.

Manually creating the static <li><a href="">button</a></li>, the jquery element completely see it. I'm fairly certain this issue has to do with the asynchronous method's callback function executing after jquery.

Comment: _"Thanks for the many replies everyone"_ - Actualy, it was just Peter :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with jQuery - the same problem would occur with plain JS as well.
Basically, you need to make sure that:

1. The links are inserted into the DOM **only when** it is ready (so your button-container is present).
2. The behaviour is attached to the links **after** they have been inserted into the DOM.

You can change your code so that the links are inserted inside of `$(document).ready(...)` (to ensure the button-container is already there) and the event-handlers are registered right after inserting the links (to ensure that the links are present in the DOM).
E.g.:

```
/* Original comments omitted for brevity */
$(document).ready(function () {
    /* The DOM is ready, so `#button-container` is guaranteed to be present */
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true } , function (tabs) {
        var currentURL = tabs[0].url;
        getCurrentURL(currentURL);
        $('#button-container').html(buildButtons());

        /* Place this inside the callback to ensure the links are present */
        $('a').parents('#button-container').click(function() {
            console.log('test');
        });
    });
});
```

---

BTW, your `$('a').parents('#button-container')` will resolve to `#button-container` (**not** to the children `a`s). If I am not mistaken, you want to target all `a`s that are inside `#button-container` and not `#button-container` itself.
To achieve this change your expression to:

```
$('#button-container a').click(function () {...});
```

Comment: Thank you ExpertSystem, I didn't realize I needed to include the .click even inside the chrome.tabs.query's call back.

Comment: Always glad to help :) BTW, if this answer helped you solve your problem, please **[mark it as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)**.